# Fetching data from table using select and count function together in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like .

```
user_circle

user_id  circle_id  user_type_id
1        1          1
1        2          1
1        3          1
1        4          2
2        2          2


user_type

id  type
1   admin
2   member
```

I have to fetch all `circle_id` from `user_circle` table where `user_id = 1` and `user_type_id = 1` and number of '`member`' (i.e: `admin` of that `circle) in that`circle` is one.

I need a result like .

```
circle_id
1
3
```

How can I achieve this? Can it be done in one query?

Comment: In your results I think it means "number of 'member' in that circle is *not* one " ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see your results it related to all `circle_id` that has no *member*, So you need this for your results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uc.circle_id
FROM user_circle uc
WHERE uc.circle_id NOT IN (
    SELECT uci.circle_id
    FROM user_circle uci
    WHERE uci.user_type_id = 2)

  AND uc.user_id = 1 AND uc.user_type_id = 1
```

---

To change above code to a `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM user_circle uc
WHERE uc.circle_id NOT IN (
    SELECT uci.circle_id
    FROM user_circle uci
    WHERE uci.user_type_id = 2)
  AND uc.user_id = 1 AND uc.user_type_id = 1
```

Comment: How can i delete those circle_id , got from this query ? do i have to run other query for deleting these circle_id , or it can be done in same query written in your answer , using DELETE clause instead of SELECT. plz response.

Comment: @Deepakkumar Just remove `SELECT` part ;).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a group by.  Something like this:

```
SELECT circle_id
FROM 
  (SELECT circle_id, user_type_id, count(*) AS total
   FROM user_circle
   WHERE user_id = 1 and user_type_id = 1
   GROUP BY user_type_id, circle_id
  ) t
WHERE total = 1
```

Comment: i tried your query . but it returned me all circle_id having user_id =1 and user_type_id =1 . i also need the circle_id which has only one member in it.